# javascript function execute in infinite when we open new tab/window in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one `onChange` function basically main job is to select the radio button. The function is working fine but the problem is `onChange` function getting stuck in infinite loop whenever i switch to new tab/window then in console we can the function is getting executed again and again without doing any kind of action.

Below is code which is written in react.

```
const radioButton = (props) => {
        const [value, setValue] = useState("");
        useEffect(() => {
      setValue(props.radioValue)
    }, [props.radioValue]);
    
    // below function getting stuck in infinite loop when we switch into new tab/window. Basically on switching the window/tab , function get executed again
    const handleRadioButton = (value) => {
        setValue(value)
    }
    return (
      <Radio
      options={props.radioOptions}
      onChange={value => handleRadioButton(value)}
      value={value}
    />
    )
    }
    
export default RadioButton;
```

Comment: There's no need to set `props.radioValue` to state, just use the prop directly

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi `setValue(props.radioValue)` does not change the state of `radioValue`

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi, I spouse @goto1 was saying that it changes the value of variable named `value` rather then value of `prop.radioValue`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your previous value for radio is equal to new value and do not update the state if they are equal.

```
 const handleRadioButton = (oldValue,value) => {
    if(oldValue === value){
      return;
    }
    setValue(value);
}


<Radio
  options={props.radioOptions}
  onChange={newValue => handleRadioButton(value,newValue)}
  value={value}
```